# Search for word in previously visited websites

Tags: google-chrome

I am currently trying to find the website from which I read a certain word / phrase.  I'm sure it's buried in my browser history somewhere but I am not keen on sifting through the hundreds of websites I browse to find it.  Is there a way to google search the websites in my browser history?

(Note I want to search the *contents* of the website, not just the title of the website)

Comment: Don't think so. (that would also have security implications. You wouldn't want your browser saving the contents on your bank account page etc...)

Comment: @Dave Yes, but can I at least have google do a normal search through the last 100 websites I visited for example, assuming they are all accessible via a simple URL.